# convert .pyw to .exe and have the command line not open

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I want the command line to not open because a `tkinter` interface will open.

I am using `pyinstaller` so it works when python isn't installed. I am using python 3.6.0.

Can I also have it so it is one `exe` file that doesn't need the other things to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the command line window, add `--windowed` to your PyInstaller command line.

To create an one-file bundle, add `--onefile` to your PyInstaller command line.

These are documented in PyInstaller's options. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options